# Angular multiple loading controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have problem with loading angular. This is my code:

```
    var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ["ngSanitize"]);
myApp.controller("MyAppController",
    function myAppController($scope, $http, $log, $rootScope, listsModel) {
        $scope.$log = $log;
    });

<div ng-app="myApp ">
    <div ng-controller="MyAppController">
        <script>console.log("A")</script>
        {{$log.debug("B")}}
    </div>
</div>
```

This code write to console this: A, **B, B** 
I think that angular loading multiple. Why? What can I do? Thanks

Comment: show us your states

Comment: @bluray: Can you show your routes?

Comment: Remove the extra space in "myApp ", there is no app to load because of the space

Comment: The doubt is that, your state/route is invoking your controller from js file, plus your html is doing it again when it is loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your controller is not loaded twice it's the digest cycle that is running twice at the beginning when the application is loaded since watch is registered to every log so it will be printed twice. It will log twice only first time moreover if there is more digest cycle it will be logged again.

Comment: Its normal? I should do something about it?

Comment: it's normal situation

Comment: @bluray It's normal because the first time it runs to check the result and the second time it runs again to check if the result is still the same.